# Fazer conversão de data C#

Tags: c#, conversão-de-tipo

tenho uma data "qua, nov 25" e gostaria de converter ela para 2015-11-25
Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Você possui apenas uma string, só com esse conteúdo? Não tem o ano?

Comment: Exato. Na realidade eu tenho que pegar uma data exibir ele no formato 'qua, nov 25' depois voltar ele para data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string strData = "qua, nov 25, 2015";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt");
string formato = "ddd, MMM dd, yyyy";
DateTime data = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParseExact(strData, formato, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out data);
```